# Is there any option that PDF can be protected from downloading?

Tags: javascript, pdf

I want to protect my website PDF files from downloading and snapshot or Ctrl+P. I read that it can be done by JavaScript but I'm unable do it.

Answer (score 1):

Not possiable

In order for the client or user to see and read the PDF, your serve needs to server it. To send a copy of it to the clients broswer. The user can always download the PDF becuase you need to send it

Comment: No we will not send it to client we upload the file in a particular server or website where client can see it but unable to download and take snap

Comment: Then how will the client be able to see it? If you never hand the client a copy of the PDF, the client will never see it. Even if you use a password to encrpt the PDF, how will the client read it? How will the client see whats inside that PDF? YOU NEED TO HAND OVER THE PASSWORD. no matter how you put it, how you do it, if you want the client to see that PDF, you have to hand it over.